# AndroidのTwitter SDKでログイン認証できない

Tags: android, twitter, oauth

私はandroid アプリ内に twitter SDK (1.8.0)を使ってtwitter#login() を実装したところ
LG Electronics LGV32 で例外が発生しました。

Twitterアプリがインストールされていない端末なので標準ブラウザ立ち上がると思うのですが、立ち上がりません。

解決策をしらないでしょうか？

```
09-25 16:30:09.491  29572-29572/PACKAGE E/Twitter﹕ Invalid json: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <hash>
    <error>Desktop applications only support the oauth_callback value 'oob'</error>
    <request>/oauth/request_token</request>
    </hash>
    com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 8 path $
            at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:65)
            at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:45)
            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException.parseApiError(TwitterApiException.java:136)
            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException.readApiError(TwitterApiException.java:125)
            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException.<init>(TwitterApiException.java:58)
            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException.convert(TwitterApiException.java:110)
            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.failure(Callback.java:45)
            at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$2.run(CallbackRunnable.java:53)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5430)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:913)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
     Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 8 path $
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1572)
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1421)
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:544)
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:427)
            at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:60)
            at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:45)
            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException.parseApiError(TwitterApiException.java:136)
            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException.readApiError(TwitterApiException.java:125)
            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException.<init>(TwitterApiException.java:58)
            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException.convert(TwitterApiException.java:110)
            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.failure(Callback.java:45)
            at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$2.run(CallbackRunnable.java:53)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5430)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:913)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
09-25 16:30:09.491  29572-29572/PACKAGE E/Twitter﹕ Failed to get request token
    com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: 401 Authorization Required
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:383)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
            at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-25 16:30:09.521  29572-29572/PACKAGE E/Twitter﹕ Authorization completed with an error
    com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Failed to get request token
            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthController$1.failure(OAuthController.java:95)
            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuth1aService$1.failure(OAuth1aService.java:215)
            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.failure(Callback.java:45)
            at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$2.run(CallbackRunnable.java:53)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5430)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:913)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

Comment: `Desktop applications only support the oauth_callback value ‘oob’`というエラーメッセージにて検索してみると、Twitterに連携アプリを登録するときのコールバックのURLが設定されていない場合に起きるとのことです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！ 試してみます！
端末に twitter アプリがはいってないと起こるみたいですね

Answer (score 1):

dev.twitter.comでアプリタイプはブラウザにしてください。

ソース：
https://twittercommunity.com/t/set-application-type-to-browser/235  
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter-development-talk/D3RP6D_Z75A

Comment: ありがとうございます。アプリタイプをブラウザにするのと、CallBack URL をなんでもいいので入力したら解決できました。
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/speg03/20091019/1255957580

Comment: @TomoyukiNagai そうですね、私の場合にmyapp.twitter://oauth